# How to display default image in iPhone App for long time?

Tags: ios, image, default

Is it possible to display Default image which is shown when iPhone/iPad App starts for long time that what it usually does? Because in my app it varies sometimes that image is displayed for long time and some time is just flashes and it loads main app.

Sumit

Comment: Rather than asking how to make your default image stay on the screen for a longer period of time, you should be trying to find out why sometimes it does stay on there longer, and reduce that time. Users should be able to work with your application as quickly as possible, not be forced to stare at a splash screen.

Answer (score 2):

Make the first view in your application show the same image as your Default image. You can even show it as a Modal and dismiss it with an animation or after a delay.

Comment: this method equivalent to [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0]; No?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];`. Just change the 1.0 to what ever you want. But Apple might not approve your app if you make it stay up too long. It goes against the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Add a 1 second delay
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this.  Don't make your application unresponsive to user input for a second every time you start up.  That's just poor design.

Comment: I just want them to read whats on default image. Sometimes that image is gone within fraction but sometime it stays there for a while. I have seen some application that shows their start up screen for while and they load their main app.

Comment: Is this a "no go" for approval-proccess? I know, that this is not good design, and i never would do that, but our customer asks us to show the launch-image for 2 Seconds.